# Operator traces in Kontsevich quantization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantization, trace, deformation-quantization

In quantization, one studies maps from functions on the phase space to operators acting on the Hilbert space. Let's fix one such map and call it $Q$.

Deformation quantization is based on the idea that $Q$ can be studied indirectly, by endowing the linear vector space of functions over the phase space with a non-commutative star product:

$$
f \star g = Q^{-1} \left( Q(f) \,Q(g) \right).
$$

Kontsevich gives an [explicit formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kontsevich_quantization_formula) for the star product that can be applied to any compact phase space and gives an associative algebra with correct behavior in the $\hbar \rightarrow 0$ limit. It is therefore often claimed that Kontsevich formula solves the long-standing problem of proving that any compact symplectic manifold admits a quantization.

However, the other important ingredient of Quantum Mechanics is the trace of an operator.
Traces are essential for making physical prediction, i.e. expectation values of observables are traces of the corresponding operators multiplied by the density matrix.

The Kontsevich formula does not give me a quantization map, only the star product.
So how do I compute $\text{tr} Q(f)$ by only knowing $f$?

One possible answer that I see is that the classical formula holds:
$$
\text{tr} Q(f) = \int \omega^{\wedge n} f.
$$

Here $\omega^{\wedge n} = \omega \wedge \omega \wedge \dots \wedge \omega$ is the volume form associated to the symplectic form $\omega$, and the integral is over the phase space.

But I have never heard anyone say definitively that indeed this phase space integral is the counterpart of the operator trace in deformation quantization, and I can't come up with a good argument to show that $\mathcal{O}(\hbar)$ corrections don't appear.

My questions are:

1. Do $\mathcal{O}(\hbar)$ corrections to the phase space integral appear in general?
2. If they do, is there an explicit formula for the trace?
3. If they do not, how do I convince myself of that?

Comment: My recollection -- supported by the wiki article you link to -- is that the Kontsevich formula does not involve a map $f\to Qf$ with $Qf$ some operator on a Hilbert space, but instead deforms the pointwise product of functions $f,g$ on phase space $(f,g)\to fg +\mathcal O(\hbar)$ directly. Perhaps list a reference where the map $Q$ is given (explicitly or implicitly)?

Comment: @alexarvanitakis you’re right and this is exactly the point I’m making in my question. Kontsevich formula needs to be augmented with a method for computing traces to be used in physics. I want to know if a consistent method exists.

Comment: Ah yes I missed *The Kontsevich formula does not give me a quantization map, only the star product*. Anyway some googling led me to arxiv.org/abs/math/0002057 which claims your formula works (in a specific sense), in Darboux coordinates (this is a corollary of the Corollary on page 4). Hopefully someone with a less superficial understanding of this than I will weigh in...

Comment: You may be trying to extend the [Weyl map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner–Weyl_transform) to arbitrary Poisson manifolds. Assuming you are comfortable with elementary flat phase space Weyl quantization, have you tried a simple example beyond trivial flat phase space? What $O(\hbar)$ corrections  in traces are you talking about? In general, the Weyl symbols of an operator contain $O(\hbar)$ corrections in undergraduate Weyl quantization; think of the angular momentum squared operator. Why shouldn't integrals of such be independent of $\hbar$?

Comment: @CosmasZachos the operators will clearly contain corrections, my confusion was about whether the corrections are also present in the trace formula or not. The classical limit of the trace should always be the integral that I wrote down, but it is not clear to me that the trace formula doesn’t acquire corrections like the Moyal product does.

Comment: $\hbar$ is a property of the star product, not of the phase space, or the integral. There is no contrast between classical or quantum phase space. The difference is in how these variables are combined in this space.

Comment: @CosmasZachos I see no reason the same $\hbar$ could not in principle appear in both the star product and the trace formula

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Full_characterization_of_the_trace) says the following properties to uniquely determine the trace operation (up to scalar multiples):

1. $\mathrm{tr}(cA) = c\mathrm{tr}(A)$
2. $\mathrm{tr}(A + B) = \mathrm{tr}(A) + \mathrm{tr}(B)$
3. $\mathrm{tr}(AB) = \mathrm{tr}(BA)$

For any linear $Q$, $\mathrm{tr} Q(f)$ will satisfy all three properties. $\int f d\Omega $ clearly satisfies (1) and (2). For (3), we want to show that $\int f \star g d\Omega = \int g \star f d\Omega $. It's easy to show that the $O(1)$ and $O(\hbar)$ terms vanish for sufficiently nice $f,g$ (using integration by parts and the equivalence of mixed partials). However, I don't understand Kontsevich graphs well enough to confidently extend this argument to higher orders in $\hbar$. If you can find a reference or an explanation, let me know. Assuming the argument does extend, we find that $\mathrm{tr} Q(f)$ and $\int f d\Omega $ are equivalent up to a scalar multiple.

Expectation values are given by $\mathrm{tr}(Q(f)\rho)$, so we can choose to normalize our trace operation such that $$\mathrm{tr}(\rho) = \int Q^{-1}(\rho)d\Omega = 1$$
This should be enough to uniquely determine all the physics. You could define in an $O(\hbar)$ term in the original integral formula, but once you normalize your density matrix it has no physical effect.

Comment: Normalization constant is not the only imaginable source of non-uniqueness, but at this point I’m not asking about uniqueness — only existence. Kontsevich star product is also not the only possible star product.

Comment: Let $Q$ be any quantization compatible with the Kontsevich formula. Then $\mathrm{tr}(Q(.))$ satisfies properties 1-3 above, so it is equivalent (up to normalization) to the integral formula you suggest. I'll try to include this in the answer.

Comment: Actually, I see what you mean - let me try to fix it.

Comment: @Daniel: the result proven in that reference is already special in that it only works for constant volume forms (see also my comment above)

Comment: I thought the reference said $$\int (f \star g) \cdot h d\Omega = \int (g \star f) \cdot h d\Omega $$
in which case $h$ would take care of variation in the volume form. Looking again, I misread the formula and the reference says something else entirely.

Comment: Ok, I think now I know how to show it for a constant volume form (without using any results from that paper). By Darboux's theorem, that should be good enough for any contractible domain, right? Is that of interest?

Comment: I expanded the Kontsevich formula up to 2-nd order and terms cancel. Not a proof by any means, but my confidence in this answer is now higher

Comment: @Daniel: I don't know if that is of interest -- I don't get the argument in your answer. Firstly the characterisation of trace breaks in infinite dimensions. More accurately functionals satisfying (3) are hard to find; most relevantly for physics ${\rm tr}(qp-pq)={\rm tr}(i\hbar)=\infty$.

Comment: Secondly as I hinted above the Kontsevich prescription doesn't come with a map $Q$. You could use the Weyl transform (for flat/contractible domains) like Cosmas Zachos suggested above in which case Wikipedia says the Weyl transform $Qf$ of $f$ is trace-class if $f$ is Schwartz, which *seems* like it does the trick (although of course you can't have $q$ or $p$ as observables in that case--polynomials aren't Schwartz) but the obvious issue there is that there is an implicit star product in the Weyl map which does not obviously agree with the Kontsevich one.

Comment: @alexarvanitakis, comment 1: This is ok, because tr(qp) and tr(pq) are both undefined. That's why I was careful to write $\int f \star g  = \int g \star f$ instead of $\int f \star g  - g \star f  = 0$. 
Comment 2: Let $S$ be the set of maps $Q$ which are compatible with the Kontsevich formula. What I say above should be valid $\forall Q \in S$. Do you know if we can say anything about $|S|$?

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov, did you find that the contributions from each 2nd-order graph vanished independently, or did you need to work with the sum of all the graphs?

Comment: Also, was $\Pi$ allowed to vary? If yes to both, then what you did probably extends to arbitrary order.

Comment: @Daniel: i suppose what I am trying to say is that it's not clear that $S$ is nonempty

Comment: @alexarvanitakis: This would make an interesting question in its own right. I have a vague idea of how a construction might go, but this comment section doesn't seem like the right place to flesh it out.

Comment: @Daniel: It pertains to your answer...

Comment: Both the question and my answer assume $S$ is nonempty. Is that what you mean?